# Turn keymap number back to key sequence

Tags: keymap

When viewing a keymap, prefix keys and keys in their maps are displayed as numerical values. E.g.

```el
(keymap
 (M-delete . sp-unwrap-sexp)
 (27 keymap
     (23 . sp-copy-sexp)
     (6 . *-forward-sexp)))
```

Keys at the top-level map, as we can see, are not numbers. Here, there is `M-delete`, which is clearly easier to understand than `27`.

Is it possible to turn these numbers back to keys sequences? How?

Comment: You can view a keymap in a human-readable way, showing key sequences as you expect, using `C-h M-k` (`describe-keymap`) from [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el). (See [Help+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HelpPlus).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `single-key-description` to convert a number into a key in string form, for example,

```el
?\C-x
     => 24

(single-key-description 24)
     => "C-x"
```

I have the following in my init file:

```el
(defun chunyang-display-number-as-char (&optional undo)
  "Display number as character, for example, display 24 as C-x.

Why? Becuase I find the output of 'C-h v help-map' is hard to
read."
  (interactive "P")
  (if undo
      (remove-overlays nil nil 'chunyang-show-number-as-char t)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let (ov)
        (while (re-search-forward "[0-9]+" nil :no-error)
          (setq ov (make-overlay (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
          (overlay-put ov 'display (single-key-description
                                    (string-to-number (match-string 0))))
          (overlay-put ov 'chunyang-show-number-as-char t))))))
```

Comment: You learn something new every day . Now, is there an inverse function that converts the string back to the number?

Comment: @TianxiangXiong Maybe `(aref (read-kbd-macro "C-x" t) 0) => 24`.

Comment: Ugh...really wish Emacs had a more straightforward API for this stuff. You'd think something as fundamental as keymaps would have every utility function anyone would want available . Thanks!